# Symfony2: update a form from event and get an object

Tags: forms, symfony, events

I have a form and a listener within it. As I have "choices" fields whose available value may depend on other field's values, I listen to the PRE_SUBMIT event. There, I re-create the choice fields with the new value.

In this listener, to analyse the user data, I do:

```
$event->getData()
```

But, from this event, it returns me an array. 
The constraint is that I need an object, in order to compute the available values. 
As far as I know, from the SUBMIT event I could get an object, but fields cannot be added any more to the form.

Is there no way to get an object ?

Comment: There is kinda contradiction - object is created after submitting form, but PRE_SUBMIT event is fired before submission. So anything you can have at this point array of data collected from request.

Comment: I always PRE_SET_DATA event when you want to modify data and form before rendering view.
Then, when I submit data, I use PRE_SUBMIT to populate form again